# Numbers in text, without having to update values from external files by hand?

Tags: external-files

I am writing a paper discussing numerical results of simulations. I am still tuning those simulations itself, so the results keep changing slightly. I don't want to re-type numbers over from what I computed all the time into the LaTeX document by hand.

I am currently using python to extract results and spit it out files in LaTeX format which are then `\include`'d (`tabular`s with numbers, basically), but this approach is not very flexible -- in particular, I can't refer to those numbers in running text.

Is there a packaged way to have e.g. text file with `name value` lines and then refer to `value` using `\name` in LaTeX, or something similar?

Comment: If you're scripting your output into LaTeX `tabular` code, rather use `\input`. Perhaps the [`datatool` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) could be of help here. It allows you to read data from a CSV file and perform operations/tests on the database entries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tell your Python script to write lines

```
\def\name{value}%
```

instead of simply

```
name value
```

to your data files to be `\input{}`ed. Then `\name` in your main document will expand to the current `value`. However, with this approach the control sequence `name` may only contain letters. For general cs names, such as letters mixed with numbers and special characters, say `name_1`,

```
\expandafter\def\csname name_1\endcsname{value}%
```

must be written to the data file.

`\csname name_1\endcsname` then expands to its value wherever you place it in your main document.

Don't forget to terminate data lines with `%`. It avoids spurious spaces in the final LaTeX output.

Comment: Nice idea! That solves the problem very elegantly.